# RSpec test for a method that contains gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do I design a RSpec test for assigning a `gets.chomp` method to an instance variable?

```
def choose
    puts "Please enter the type you want:"
    @type = gets.chomp
    puts "Thank you, now please enter how many of those you want:"
    @quantity = gets.chomp
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stubs/mocks for that. But the main question is: where did you place `def choose`? It's important since i'll stub it's calls on some object.

Let imagine you have this method in `class Item`:

```
class Item
  def choose
    puts "Please enter the type you want:"
    @type = gets.chomp
    puts "Thank you, now please enter how many of those you want:"
    @quantity = gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Then i'll be able to stub `gets` and `chomp` calls to simulate user's input:

```
RSpec.describe Item do
  describe '#choose' do
    before do
      io_obj = double
      expect(subject)
        .to receive(:gets)
        .and_return(io_obj)
        .twice
      expect(io_obj)
        .to receive(:chomp)
        .and_return(:type)
      expect(io_obj)
        .to receive(:chomp)
        .and_return(:quantity)
    end

    it 'sets @type and @quantity according to user\'s input' do
      subject.choose

      expect(subject.instance_variable_get(:@type)).to eq :type
      expect(subject.instance_variable_get(:@quantity)).to eq :quantity
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm @alexander, is the .twice a keyword? I need the same but for three times

Comment: Oh never mind @alexander I found my answer here on Relish...https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts